# Unity Expansion files download finished

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently working on an APK expansion file but I am unable to test expansion file download from Google play. I did exactly [what it told me to do](http://labs.exoa.fr/tutorial-unity-4-apk-splitting-google-play-obb/) but when I run my app, it's just stuck at the downloading UI screen with 0MB/0MB. A msg is printed "download finished" but there is no obb in sdcard.

I did set the BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY the same as in my GooglePlay publisher account. I did upload both APK and the expansion file on GooglePlay as a draft. I am running the app in Unity.

So did I miss something else? Do I need to provide some kind of URL? If so how do I get the URL and where to set it?

Answer (score 0):

To test the google play OBB downloader, you have to download version you are testing directly from google play to your android device after uploading the app with the expansion file. You can download the version even if it still in draft by releasing it as alpha/beta and creating a test group as shown in the link below. Also give to several hours for the app to propagate.

https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/about/distribution.html#advanced

Also, from what I experienced, I found that every time you build the APK+OBB version, the OBB will only work with the APK that generated along with it, so make sure you upload the correct APK+OBB.